# How pass value in ContentDialog from any page in uwp?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

i have to need to pass value from page to Contentdialog. plz help me out

How pass value in ContentDialog from any page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overload constructor.
For example if you have standard constructor without parameters

```
   public ContentDialog1()
    {
     this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Just add a new one:

```
   public ContentDialog1(string param)
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And when you call dialog you can pass parameter in:

```
     ContentDialog1 cd = new ContentDialog1("some info");
     await cd.ShowAsync();
```